# Slideshow that works on IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zodrWy)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#barousel_prevnextnav').barousel({
            navType: 2
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barousel_prevnextnav" class="barousel">
                <div class="barousel_image">
                    <!-- image 1 -->
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=100&bg=cccccc&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1200%C3%97400&w=1200&h=400" alt="" class="default" />
                    <!-- image 2 -->
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=100&bg=cccccc&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1200%C3%97400&w=1200&h=400" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="barousel_content">
                    <!-- content 1 -->
                    <div class="default">
                        [any html content]
                    </div>
                    <!-- content 2 -->
                    <div>
                        [any html content]
                    </div>
                    <!-- content xx -->
                    <div>
                        [any html content]
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="barousel_nav">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I found this library

[link](http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel/)

I tried to implement this library and to make it work but unfortunately not work.

I do not understand what the problem is, I respected all write in the documentation.
You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use a lower version of jQuery (*1.x*), version 3.x is only supported in IE 9+. That said this example isn't working in a modern browser either.

Comment: and where they can find to download older versions of jquery? are on the official website? Can you give me a link please?

Comment: Yes they are, [here is a link to them](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/). That said this example isn't working on my modern Firefox browser, there could be another non-browser related problem here. Remove your extra `<div> [any html content] </div>` that's probably causing an issue.

Comment: I don't have IE 7 on this machine, did you make sure to change jQuery to version 1.x? Note that [`1.12` was the last version to support IE 6 and 7](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/04/02/browser-support-in-jquery-1-12-and-beyond/), it needs to be an older version.

Comment: The problem is that neither walks on chrome slider

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"neither walks on chrome slider"*.

Comment: sorry for my English, I wanted to say at the moment slider not working in any browsers, not only in IE7

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENvPMz) is the codepen with the removed `<div>`, it appears to be somewhat working. As in the two click-able elements on the bottom seem to switch between images. On the initial page loads it seems to still show both the elements and only show a single image once one of the "arrows" are clicked.

Comment: [Here's a working example in Firefox](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aByNoe). Some CSS needs to be added as well (see codepen), or the slider won't function correctly. Test this in IE7 to see if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this slider http://responsiveslides.com/

it works properly on IE7 and its very light weight
Only dependency is jQuery (1.6 and up supported) and that all the images are same size.

so you can use lower version of jquery from 1.6

see if this works for you